# Join two XML files with a matching node in php

Tags: php, xml

I need to connect 2 hml with a key. I used the code found here. But I can't use it.
I tried to look for similar questions and solutions here. But they were with the same field name "ProductCode". My task is more complicated. The identifiers are different, but the values are the same.
"ProductCode" and "WIC"

xml1

```
<ProductCode>VCQP620V2-PB</ProductCode>
<Vendor>PNY</Vendor>
<ProductType>Графические процессоры</ProductType>
<ProductCategory>Видеокарты</ProductCategory>
<ProductDescription>PNY NVIDIA QUADRO P620</ProductDescription>
<ProductCard>https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=200331123012134965&amp;THEME=asbis&amp;LANG=ru</ProductCard>
<AttrList>
  <element Name="Стандарт разъема подключения" Value="PCI Express 3.0 x16"/>
</AttrList>
<Images>
  <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/600x600x600x600/200401160012256800.jpg</Image>
</Images>
```

xml2

```
<CONTENT>
<COMP_CODE>720</COMP_CODE>
<LANG>ru</LANG>
<COMP_CODE_BUYER>210629085533538169</COMP_CODE_BUYER>
<SEARCH_CODE></SEARCH_CODE>
<MANUFACTURER_NAME></MANUFACTURER_NAME>
<TYPE_NAME></TYPE_NAME>
<SUPPLY_TYPE></SUPPLY_TYPE>
<PRICES>
    <PRICE>
        <WIC>VCQP620V2-PB</WIC>
        <DESCRIPTION>PNY NVIDIA QUADRO P620 2GB GDDR5, 128-bit, PCIEx16 2.0, mini DP 1.4 x4, Active cooling, TDP 40W, LP, Retail (4 х mDP на DP, 1 × mDP to DVI-D SL, 1 x LP Bracket included)</DESCRIPTION>
        <VENDOR_NAME>PNY</VENDOR_NAME>
        <GROUP_NAME>Graphics Processing Unit</GROUP_NAME>
        <VPF_NAME/>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>KZT</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <AVAIL>0</AVAIL>
        <RETAIL_PRICE>103857.95</RETAIL_PRICE>
        <MY_PRICE>103857.95</MY_PRICE>
        <WARRANTYTERM>24</WARRANTYTERM>
        <GROUP_ID>852</GROUP_ID>
        <VENDOR_ID>170544</VENDOR_ID>
        <SMALL_IMAGE>https://www.it4profit.com/catalogimg/wic/1/VCQP620V2-PB</SMALL_IMAGE>
        <PRODUCT_CARD>https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=200331123012134965&amp;THEME=asbis&amp;LANG=ru</PRODUCT_CARD>
        <EAN/>
    </PRICE>
</PRICES>
```

Combine XML. I would like to get it like this.

```
<ProductCode>VCQP620V2-PB</ProductCode>

<Vendor>PNY</Vendor>

<ProductType>Графические процессоры</ProductType>

<ProductCategory>Видеокарты</ProductCategory>

<ProductDescription>PNY NVIDIA QUADRO P620</ProductDescription>
<Image>https://www.it4profit.com/catalogimg/wic/1/VCQP620V2-PB</Image>
<ProductCard>https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=200331123012134965&amp;THEME=asbis&amp;LANG=ru</ProductCard>

<RETAIL_PRICE>103857.95</RETAIL_PRICE>
<MY_PRICE>103857.95</MY_PRICE>
<AVAIL>0</AVAIL>


<AttrList>
  <element Name="Стандарт разъема подключения" Value="PCI Express 3.0 x16"/>
</AttrList>
<Images>
  <Image>https://content.it4profit.com/pimg/s/resize/600x600x600x600/200401160012256800.jpg</Image>
</Images>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM+Xpath allows you to target and copy nodes:

You XML missed some parent elements. I added some to get valid XML and removed some of the unaffected/unused leaf elements.

Here is an explained example:

```
// bootstrap the XML documents
$mainDocument = new DOMDocument();
$mainDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$mainDocument->loadXML(getMainXML());
$mainXpath = new DOMXpath($mainDocument);

$dataDocument = new DOMDocument();
$mainDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dataDocument->loadXML(getDataXML());
$dataXpath = new DOMXpath($dataDocument);

// iterate the Product elements
foreach ($mainXpath->evaluate('//Product') as $product) {
    // get the Product Code
    $productCode = $mainXpath->evaluate('string(ProductCode)', $product);
    
    // Look for the first PRICE with a matching WIC
    foreach ($dataXpath->evaluate("(//PRICE[WIC='$productCode'])[1]") as $price) {
        
        // any child element (*), filtered by element name
        $nodesToCopy = $dataXpath->evaluate(
            '*[self::RETAIL_PRICE or self::MY_PRICE or self::AVAIL]',
            $price
        );
        foreach ($nodesToCopy as $node) {
            // import and append
            $product->appendChild($mainDocument->importNode($node, TRUE));
        }  
    }
}


$mainDocument->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $mainDocument->saveXML();


function getMainXML() {
    return <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>VCQP620V2-PB</ProductCode>
        <Vendor>PNY</Vendor>
        <ProductType>Графические процессоры</ProductType>
        <ProductCategory>Видеокарты</ProductCategory>
    </Product>
</Products>
XML;
}

function getDataXML() {
    return <<<'XML'
<CONTENT>
    <PRICES>
        <PRICE>
            <WIC>VCQP620V2-PB</WIC>
            <CURRENCY_CODE>KZT</CURRENCY_CODE>
            <AVAIL>0</AVAIL>
            <RETAIL_PRICE>103857.95</RETAIL_PRICE>
            <MY_PRICE>103857.95</MY_PRICE>
            <WARRANTYTERM>24</WARRANTYTERM>
            <GROUP_ID>852</GROUP_ID>
            <VENDOR_ID>170544</VENDOR_ID>
            <EAN/>
        </PRICE>
    </PRICES>
</CONTENT>
XML;
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <ProductCode>VCQP620V2-PB</ProductCode>
    <Vendor>PNY</Vendor>
    <ProductType>Графические процессоры</ProductType>
    <ProductCategory>Видеокарты</ProductCategory>
    <AVAIL>0</AVAIL>
    <RETAIL_PRICE>103857.95</RETAIL_PRICE>
    <MY_PRICE>103857.95</MY_PRICE>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

However, if you documents are very large you might need look into XMLReader and a temporary database import.